# PHP sprintf vulnerability?

Tags: php, format-string

On some sites such as WriteCodeOnline, [`sprintf`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), [`vsprintf`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) and other related formatted string functions are disabled for security reasons:

> **Warning:** vsprintf() has been disabled for security reasons on line **1**

I'm wondering what these security reasons are. I've already read the Wikipedia article on [Uncontrolled format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) but it only addresses the aspects of using `printf` in C.

What are the security issues of executing `*printf` on PHP? Obviously the function isn't meant for preventing SQL injections, but that's a matter of using the correct tool for the job.

Comment: If you include unfiltered user content as the input, you're enabling XSS. Taint has to be removed.

Comment: But XSS is also possible with `echo` if the input is untrusted

Comment: "but it only addresses the aspects of using printf in C" - True, but that works well in php too.

Comment: @Gerifield - Yep, given that perl and php which is related to it are based on a subset of C conventions, there is an issue of inheritance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895838/php-sprintf-considered-harmful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's not C/C++ language; however, perl, PHP, ruby and java are descendents that carry on various C language conventions. By not having %n, php gets rid of part of the problem, but it still has %x which can be exploitable under certain circumstances.

Basically, `printf()` and its variants can allow control of the format string **if you don't specify it**.

Unvalidated user input can supply the format string of their choosing that will lead to a buffer overflow like condition (not a true buffer overflow).

Modern perl and PHP will throw warnings during the development phase so you don't create code missing the format string, if you choose to ignore them, you can have an issue.

Since the site you're referencing allows you to put in any old darn thing to test code, they are preventing creative format strings being entered into `printf()` that can eat memory, create a denial of service attack, cause premature program termination or crash the PHP interpreter *on that website*.

[Format String Vulnerability](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf) in C

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. Is there an example somewhere that demonstrates an exploit with `%x`? I would assume that `%x` performs something like JavaScript's `parseInt(foo, 16)` on the variable. Also I think that suppressed warnings would silently fail but is there a security issue with that?

Answer (score 2):

Not in any traditional sense, as PHP's sprintf doesn't support any of the really dangerous conversions like %n. A user-controlled format string can still cause some limited havoc (consider %99999999s), but about the worst, It could do would be to consume memory and time.

following is an integer overflow. Which leads to the following code:-

```
<?php
echo sprintf('%2147483646$s', "foo"); # Warning: Too few arguments
echo sprintf('%2147483647$s', "foo"); # Warning: Argument number must be greater than zero
```

[PHP Bug #61531](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61531)